# PyQt – Load data from .txt file via Drag and Drop

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have a folder TreeView on the left layout and I want to drag a .txt file from there and drop it to the other layout. Hopefully, I want to load the data of that dropped file on a variable.

For the code’s needs, I used till now (to my “real” code) the np.loadtxt() to load the data, so I’d like to use it here too.
In case it matters, the .txt file contains 4 columns (coordinates).

I post my code. The program closes when I drop the file.

Thanks in advance!

```
import sys, time, os

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

import random

class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


        self.folderLayout = QWidget();

        self.pathRoot = QDir.rootPath()

        self.dirmodel = QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.dirmodel.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())

        self.indexRoot = self.dirmodel.index(self.dirmodel.rootPath())

        self.folder_view = QTreeView();
        self.folder_view.setDragEnabled(True)
        self.folder_view.setModel(self.dirmodel)
        self.folder_view.setRootIndex(self.indexRoot)

        self.selectionModel = self.folder_view.selectionModel()

        self.left_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.left_layout.addWidget(self.folder_view)

        self.folderLayout.setLayout(self.left_layout)        

        splitter_filebrowser = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter_filebrowser.addWidget(self.folderLayout)
        splitter_filebrowser.addWidget(Figure_Canvas(self))
        splitter_filebrowser.setStretchFactor(1, 1)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(splitter_filebrowser)

        self.centralWidget().setLayout(hbox)


        self.setWindowTitle('Simple drag & drop')
        self.setGeometry(750, 100, 600, 500)



class Figure_Canvas(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        blabla = QLineEdit()

        self.right_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.right_layout.addWidget(blabla)


        self.buttonLayout = QWidget()
        self.buttonLayout.setLayout(self.right_layout)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):

        if e.mimeData().hasFormat('text/uri-list'):
            e.accept()
        else:
            e.ignore() 

    def dropEvent(self, e):

        print("something")
        data = np.loadtxt(e.mimeData())
        print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: PyQt5 unfortunately silences error messages in slots. Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740884/preventing-pyqt-to-silence-exceptions-occurring-in-slots and then report with the concrete stack trace and error message.

Comment: I mean the solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18980089/1536976

Answer (score 0):

## Clarify the Issue

From where the `.txt` file is dragged and dropped and the contents of that file are unimportant. The heart of the question is: **How can you open a file in `PyQt` by dragging and dropping it?**.

### Example Solution

Here is a simple implementation of the desired functionality; namely, **drag-and-drop**:

```py
"""
Adapted from a ZetCode PyQt6 tutorial
and the Calculator tutorial by RealPython

This simple program demonstrates the mechanism
to read the contents of a .txt file by merely 
dragging and dropping a given file onto the field
set to accept drags and drops.

Tested using:

Python 3.11.0
PyQt6  6.6.0


BONUS TIP:
If you would like to check which version of PyQt6 you 
have installed, run the following commend from the 
virtual environment in your terminal:

    py -m pip show PyQt6

If you are not using a virtual environment yet,
simply run the command.
"""


import sys

from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QPushButton,
    QWidget,
    QLabel,
    QTextEdit,
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
)


class DragDropTXTWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        for url in event.mimeData().urls():
            path_to_file = url.path()[1:]
            if path_to_file.endswith("txt"):
                with open(path_to_file, encoding="utf-8") as f:
                    print(f.read())


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # Set up the main window's name and size:
        self.setWindowTitle("Drag and Drop a .txt File")
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)

        # Set up the layout for the DragDropTXTWidget
        # and add the DragDropTXTWidget as the main
        # window's central widget:
        self.generalLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        dragDropWidget = DragDropTXTWidget(self)
        dragDropWidget.setLayout(self.generalLayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(dragDropWidget)

        # Additional UI components:
        self._addLabel()

    def _addLabel(self) -> None:
        """Create a label to identify the drag/drop field.
        """
        statement = """
Drag and drop a .txt file onto this field.
The results will be printed to the console.
"""
        dragDropLabel = QLabel(statement)

        # Add some style: center-alignment and
        # a faded look for the text:
        dragDropLabel.setObjectName("label")
        dragDropLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel#label { color: gray }")
        dragDropLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        self.generalLayout.addWidget(dragDropLabel)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

### Explanation

In the `DragDropTXTWidget` class, we inherit the properties of a basic QWidget and override two methods: `dragEnterEvent()` and `dropEvent()`.

In this section...

```py
def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
    if event.mimeData().hasUrls():
        event.accept()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

...the `if`/`else` block ensures that there is at least **one** URL to open.

This section of code...

```py
def dropEvent(self, event):
    for url in event.mimeData().urls():
        path_to_file = url.path()[1:]
        if path_to_file.endswith("txt"):
            with open(path_to_file, encoding="utf-8") as f:
                print(f.read())
```

...does the actual work. It loops through the URLs stored in `event`'s `mimeData()` method.

As for this line: `path_to_file = url.path()[1:]`, this example was tested on a Windows 11 machine, not Linux. Before being sliced, the path began like this: `/C://...`. The first `/` had to be skipped.

The `if` statement ensures that only a `.txt` file will be opened; anything else will be skipped.

> This can be changed to whichever file needs to be opened.

### Conclusion

For this example, I used `Python`'s built-in `open()` class, (`with open(path_to_file, encoding="utf-8") as f:`), but anything that can open a `.txt` file can be used in its place.

And, of course, you would never merely print the file's contents to the console. What to do with the contents, however, is beyond the scope of this answer.

While this answer uses `PyQt6` instead of `PyQt5`, the concepts are identical.