# How to handle error in PyQt5 by rewriting sys.excepthook?

Tags: python, error-handling, pyqt5, sys

I learned that PyQt silences the error, and this issue can be resolved by rewriting `sys.excepthook`. Moreover, I have consulted this two posted [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740884/preventing-pyqt-to-silence-exceptions-occurring-in-slots) and [link2](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-qt/issues/25), both of which are about the same issue.

However, I could not figure out what `sys.excepthook` does and how to transfer other`s solution to solve my own problem. Hopefully, you guys can shed me some light on this.

I have `class Model` with function,

```
def updateFilename(self, filename):
    if filename is None:
        raise type_exc.PathIsEmpty("You have not chosen any file yet")
    else:
        self._filename = filename
```

And then, in another file,

```
def encodeVideo(self):
    try:
        self.model.updateFilename(self.fileName)
    except type_exc.PathIsEmpty as e:
        self.errorDialog.errorTypeChanged(e)
        self.errorDialog.show()
```

My intention is to use `try except` as usual, and activate an error displaying dialog when error occurs.  But what my code really does, is autonomously exiting when an error takes place.

Comment: Run the code in a console (or command window) so that you can see the traceback. And see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33741755/984421).

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks, it helps me debug an error which prevents my code functioning as expected. For the record, `try except` works in my case without manipulating with `sys.excepthook` .